# What type of statistic or probability is this?

Tags: web-services, statistics

Let's say I go to 200 sites that are about suggested browser. Next, let's say that I track how many times I hear Chrome suggested, IE suggested, Firefox, etc...

Looks something like this (** note: these are made up values)...

120 - IE
90 - Chrome
55 - Firefox

from these numbers, I can more objectively determine that I should build my page to match those using IE, then chrome and last firefox...

What is the name of this type of data gathering? It's hard to research something when you don't know the name of it.

Comment: One of the metrics for this is called "Browser market share"

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a **reliable** " Usage share of web browsers" source.

One of the most reliable source is [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers).
You will learn that the actual distribution of web browsers is hard to measure and that different sources do not agree.

Yet, you can bet that the ranking should be something like :

Chrome > Internet Explorer > Firefox > Safari.

Please do note that when saying for example Chrome, they mean all the different versions of Chrome, etc.

If you already have a website, the best way to get more accurate statistics about your web traffic is to use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).